# aggregate by column value and paste row values together in SAS

Tags: sas, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I have a data set that looks like:

Have:

```
data have;

input a b c d e f g h ;

datalines;

1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0

0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1

;

run;
```

The columns a, b, c and d are four options to the question 1 on a 4-point scale. The value "1" in obs1 column A signifies that respondent has chosen option A for that question which signifies 4 on the 4 point scale.

a = 4, b = 3, c = 2 and d = 1.

The next question's options are e, f, g and h. The respondent has chosen option g which is 2 on the 4 point scale. e = 4, f = 3, g = 2 and h = 1.

The data set contains hundreds of columns like this. My idea is to collapse 4 columns into one getting values like : "1000", "0100", "0010", "0001" and then converting 1000 = 4, 0100 = 3, 0010 = 2 and 0001 = 1.

I want it to be like :

```
block   col1    col2    col3    col4
1       1000    0100    0010    0001
2       0100    0010    1000    0001
3       1000    0100    1000    0010
```

I've gotten this far:

```
proc transpose data = have out = have_t;
run;

data have_t_block;
set have_t;
retain block;
if _n_ = 1 then block = 1;
if mod(_n_/4,1) = 0.25 and _n_ gt 1 then block +1;
run;
```

Is there a way to concatenate the row values while aggregating by block in SAS? I do this in R, like this:

```
#Create data    
data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 0, 0), b = c(0, 1, 0), c = c(0, 0, 1), d = c(0, 0, 0), e = c(0, 1, 0), f = c(1, 0, 0), g = c(0, 0, 1), h = c(0, 0, 0), i = c(0, 0, 1), j = c(1, 0, 0), k = c(0, 0, 0), l = c(0, 1, 0))

#transpose
data <- data.frame(t(data))

#create a key for each group of 4
data$block <- rep(1:(nrow(data)/4), each = 4)

#convert data to long format and group by key (block) and use paste to concatenate
require(reshape2)
data_melt <- melt(data, id = c("block"))
trial <- data.frame(t(dcast(data_melt, block ~ variable, paste, collapse = "")))
```

Comment: What do you mean by concatenate the row values.  Do you mean concatenate the four variables into one 4-char long string?

Comment: Also - it's not apparent at least to me how you get from HAVE to WANT.  What is the relationship?  What parts of the wanted output come from the original HAVE?

Comment: Ok let me give some context in the question.

Comment: yes, concatenate the 4 variables into one 4 char long string. I've edited the question to explain the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

First off, unless you misexplained your data, your transpose didn't help things very much here as there's no particular reason to have this have one column for each respondent - let's just have one column, period.  Here's a better way to do this.

```
data have_t;
  set have;
  array cols a--h;
  do _i = 1 to dim(cols);
    value = cols[_i];
    output;
  end;
  keep value; *and an ID I hope?;
run;
```

Making a dataset 'vertical' (one column) is very easy.   Just loop over an array of all of your columns, for each set a common variable to that value, output.  Normally i'd keep track of the variable name I was outputting also, but perhaps that's not necessary.

For your main problem, what you'll want to do is use `retain`, most likely, not dissimilar to how you handle block.  Here I just calculate score directly:

```
data want;
  set have_t;
  retain score;
  counter = mod(_n_,4);
  if counter=1 then block+1; *slightly easier version of what you wrote;
  if value=1 then score = 5-counter; *first=4, second=3, third=2, fourth=1;
  if counter=0 then output;
  *We never "clear" score here - to be safer you may want to do that in the if counter=1 block;
run;
```

If you want the intermediate '0010' or whatever, you can include that as well.

```
data want;
  set have_t;
  retain score int_Value;
  length int_Value $4;
  counter = mod(_n_,4);
  if counter=1 then block+1; *slightly easier version of what you wrote;
  if value=1 then score = 5-counter; *first=4, second=3, third=2, fourth=1;
  int_value = cats(int_value,value);
  if counter=0 then do;
    output;
    int_value=' ';  *have to clear this every 4;
    score=.;  *here we might as well clear it; 
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe . . i wanted my output to look horizontal - Questions in columns.

Comment: Then you need to start with this, and do two things.  One, have some way to identify a question number - that might be a counter you re-set for each id, or you might output it during the transposition (assuming your variable names might have the question number built in for example).  Then two, you need to `proc transpose` back by your respondent ID and Question, using `id` option `id question_var_name;` or whatever it is called and `by respondent_id;` or whatever that is called.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly,try this:

```
data want;
  do i=1 by 1 until(last.block);
  set have_t_block;
  array var $4. var1-var4;
  array col col1-col4;
  length var1-var4 $4.;
  by block notsorted;
  do over var;
  var=cats(var,col);
  end;
  if last.block then output;
  end;
  keep var: block;
run;
```

Comment: Why do you `do i=1 by 1 until (last.block)`?  What does this buy you over regular datastep looping?

Comment: [and just to be clear I'm not arguing with it per se - but asking for an explanation.]  In general, code-without-explanation is as bad as a question without code: unless it's something really trivial and obvious, it doesn't help future readers nearly as much as explaining *why* it works, and why you do what you do.